# Divide two dataframe by matching part of the strings in Index

Tags: pandas, multi-index

Please help, why df3 is not working? got error "merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented"

raw data:
LastName    FirstName   Year    Cat    Pay
0   Johnson        David    2020    Apple   100
1   Bird            Demi    2020    Apple   60
2   Bird            Demi    2019    Banana  100
3   Johnson        David    2019    Banana  100

df1=df.groupby(['LastName', 'FirstName']) ['Pay'].agg(['min','max', 'mean', 'sum'])

df2 = df.groupby(['LastName','FirstName','Year'])['Pay'].mean()

df3=pd.DataFrame()
df3["PCT"] = df1['mean']/df2

Comment: Hello! You will be more likely to get help if you can provide us with some complete code to replicate your problem. As well as giving us the desired output.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("hello.xls")
df1=df.groupby(['LastName', 'FirstName']) ['Pay'].agg(['min','max', 'mean', 'sum'])

df2 = df.groupby(['LastName','FirstName','Year'])['Pay'].mean()

df3=pd.DataFrame()
df3["PCT"] = df1['mean']/df2`

Comment: Instead of a comment, please try to edit your original question. Provide a short example of  what your dataframe looks like. It is hard to tell what your data looks like when you load an external file. You can, for instance, show us the first 5-10 rows of your data. Do all of this as an edit to your original post. Also include what you have tried so far and your desired output.